# ComplextType.rejectChanges sets wrong original values?

Tags: knockout.js, breeze

This seems like bug but I'm not sure. Within the same data context/tracked changes session,

1. create an entity (that has a complex type).
2. Make a change to a string property of the complex type of the entity created. "test"
3. save changes (accepting all changes).
4. reload from db/remote source the same entity.
5. make changes to the same string property of the complex type. "testED"
6. Call manager.RevertChanges()..
   --> the property of the complex type should have been reverted to state at #3 ("test"). Instead it reverts to "".

I inspected the breeze code and saw that when processing the revertChangesCore method, the complext type's original value does in fact show "" instead of "test".

For whatever reason, the way I've hacked a fix to this is by resetting the originalValues list of the complexType by calling the following code before step #5:

```
myEntity().ComplexType1().complexAspect.originalValues = [];
```

Any thoughts to what could be causing the original values to be wrong? It seems like this happens specifically when you create a new entity not when loading an existing one from the db.

Answer (score 0):

I just created a test against Breeze v 1.4.5 to replicate this and I don't see the bug. After the second 'revert' my complexType property reverts to 'test' not ''.  What version of breeze are you running?

Comment: it's breeze.client nuget package v1.4.4. does the fact that resetting original values fixing this mean that maybe I should be calling acceptChanges explicitly after step #3 or after it is reloaded maybe?

Comment: No, you shouldn't need to do either, acceptChanges is effectively called after any save.  Could you try Breeze 1.4.5 and see if that fixes the issue?

Comment: i know it's called after any save... was hoping there was a chance that maybe the bug in breeze was around that part - calling acceptChanges after save... seems like an easier bug to fix.

I will update this ticket once I have some time to update to 1.4.5.. any breaking changes to be concerned with?